# Timeline of an answer; acceptance

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, timeline

Can we see when an answer has been accepted in the timeline of that answer? (I've tried it, but to no avail.)

If not, where can I see this?

Comment: Some related posts on [meta.se]: [Accept vote isn't shown in an accepted answer's timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359782) and [Add answer acceptance timestamp to the post timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368647).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to be correct that the acceptance time does not appear to be shown anywhere in the timeline.  However, you can see it directly on the answer itself by hovering over the checkmark that indicates it was accepted.

Comment: The timeline of any answer now has an entry for answer acceptance (cf. [Kyle Pollard's answer to 'New timeline view only shows \*last\* accept vote, no un-accepts'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383284) on Meta SE.

Answer (score 10):

To supplement Eric Wofsey's answer:

Answers accepted less than three days ago are shown as

> The question owner accepted this as the best answer [X hours ago]/[yesterday]/[2 days ago].

rather than the exact time

> The question owner accepted this as the best answer [month] [day] at [hour]:[minute].

In this case, one can go through the Reputation tab of the answerer's account to obtain the exact time of acceptance.